# Create an array of div children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have some rows with inputs. I want to create an array for each row which contains values of the inputs. So if I have 3 rows, and values of 'input1' are 1, values of 'input2' are 2 and values of 'input3' are 3, the array would look like this:

```
[
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3]
]
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <input id="input1">
        <input id="input2">
        <input id="input3">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <input id="input1">
        <input id="input2">
        <input id="input3">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <input id="input1">
        <input id="input2">
        <input id="input3">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do it in jQuery?

Comment: You really shouldn't duplicate **ID**'s. ID's are supposed to be a unique identifier. Also that isn't an `array`.

Comment: you need to use [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) or in jquery you can create an element like `$("<div></div>")`.
Then to assign you use `document.appendChild` or in jquery `.append`

Comment: @imixtron I think you are confused to what the OP is asking for. The OP isn't wanting to create/append elements. Those elements already exist on the page, the OP wants to get the values of each input and place them into an *"array"*

Comment: I'm creating the rows by clicking a button in JS, so therefore the ID's are duplicated. So how am I supposed to do it?

Comment: @XenzLSD Then I would recommend you modify them before appending them. Duplicating `ID`'s can cause problems when working with `javascript`

Comment: @NewToJS Is there any other way? Without making multiple inputs with different ID's. If I create 10 rows with 3 inputs each, it doesn't look good with ID's from input1 to input30. I want to make it simplier. Like create a loop of rows and then get the input values of each row individually.

Comment: Something like: row[0] = input input input, row[1] = input input input, row[2] = input input input

Comment: Do you really need to use the `ID` attribute for anything? If not then simply remove it. Here's a [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/s08xss8o/) that will loop through each `.row` and use that row index for the `object` property name and place the values of the child inputs into an array in that property

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question I would do something like this:

```
var obj = {};

$('.row').each(function(ind1) {

  obj[ind1] = {};

  $(this).children().each(function (ind2) {

    obj[ind1][ind2] = $(this).val();

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <input class="input1">
        <input class="input2">
        <input class="input3">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <input class="input1">
        <input class="input2">
        <input class="input3">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <input class="input1">
        <input class="input2">
        <input class="input3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var data = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];

$('.container .row').each(function(row) {
  $(this).children().each(function (column) {
    $(this).val(data[row][column]);
  });
});
```

OR

HTML:

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var data = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  var arr = data[i];
  var row = $(".container").append("<div class='row'></div>");
  for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
    var i_name = 'input-'+i+'-'+j;
    row.append('<input id="'+i_name+'" type="text" name="'+i_name+'" value="'+arr[j]+'">');
  }
}
```